# Using different ide's for javascript/java

Tags: java, angularjs, eclipse, webstorm

I'm working on a project that has mix of angularjs/java . I like Eclipse for working with Java but find that its javascript/jQuery/AngularJS support is somewhat lacking. I've been using jetbrains webstorm for learning AngularJS and find that its a really nice tool for javascript/jQuery/AngularJS development. This is fine for proof of concepts etc but there will come a time when want to use Java / with Webstorm.

I'm aware there is a Webstorm plugin for Intellij but I cannot change from current Eclipse IDE .

A possible solution would be to create a new project that contains just AngualarJS/jQuery code and manage this using webstorm and continue to use Eclipse for java related projects.

Are there project setup's to handle this type of problem - use two IDE's to separately manage different source code languages ?

Comment: I use Netbeans which has good integration with Chrome (through Netbeans-chrome integration plugin) which lets you put debug points in any of your js sources. But I understand that you do not want to move to a new IDE. Now that you are planning to use WebStorm for JS and Eclipse for Java EE but I don't fully understand what you mean by "Are there project setup's to handle this type of problem". You should be able to separate out and manage AngularJS client src and Java EE service src on different IDEs without a problem. What difficulty are you facing with such workflow?

Comment: @user1324816 I don't have any difficulty except having to switch between IDE's to manage different source. Also there code be java logic mixed with .jsp files which also contain jQuery which makes this management more difficult. I just wanted to check if other dev's have exp similar issues what they have done to resolve them.

Comment: I suggest you to try [AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse) which provides syntax coloring, completion, hyperlink, hover and validations in HTML editor and completion for angular in Javascript Editor. As it is based on tern.js (the javascript inference engine), you can benefit with jQuery completion too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can continue to use Eclipse and install angularjs-eclipse, see  https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse .

[image]

[image]

There is also [JSDT jQuery](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jsdt-jquery/) but I cannot tell its status.

So ideally you can set-up the same project in both IDEs and selected features that works the best.

Comment: For jQuery, if you install AngularJS Eclipse, you can benefit too with jQuery https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-jQuery-support

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, it may help you:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/exporting-intellij-idea-projects-to-eclipse.html